# ¿Cómo utilizar Git para trabajar en un mismo proyecto en un equipo distribuido?

Tags: git

Tengo unas dudas con git, bueno, los comandos y tal los conozco, pero tengo dudas de cómo organizarme. Os cuento un poco mi caso:

Yo suelo trabajar con dos ordenadores, uno en casa y otro en el trabajo (No trabajo de programador, pero en el tiempo libre hago cosillas). Si tengo un proyecto en github, mi duda es como debo hacer para programar en ese proyecto desde los dos ordenadores.

A ver si me orientáis un poco sobre la forma correcta de trabajar con git.

EDITO:

Si yo clono el repositorio en los dos ordenadores, en los dos estaría usando la rama "master", entonces si, por ejemplo, una tarde por lo que sea no subo los cambios que hice en el trabajo, luego al llegar a casa ¿Puedo seguir con normalidad?

Y si en cada uno de los ordenadores tengo una rama diferente, la forma de hacer es ¿una rama para cada tarea? Es decir, en el ordenador del trabajo creo una rama para desarrollar ciertas características del programa, luego en casa hago otra para desarrollar por otra parte y así, cada rama para una tarea.

Comment: La pregunta me parece interesante y las respuestas son más interesantes todavía. Lo malo es que todas son correctas, ¿por qué? Porque son opiniones. Creo que la pregunta ya tiene muy buenas opiniones, y debería ser cerrada, pero no eliminada.

Answer (score 12):

Existen ciertas buenas prácticas recomendadas para equipos de desarrollo, el cual se suele llamar *Git Flow* o flujo de trabajo con Git. Esto permite tener un estándar de desarrollo y organizar correctamente el desarrollo de un proyecto para tener una visión todo el tiempo del proceso, el cual es:

[image: GitFlow]

Te explico el gráfico:

1. **Master**: Es la rama (*branch*) que tiene la última versión productiva del código.
2. **Release**: Es la rama que contiene los nuevos features terminados que se van desarrollando para el siguiente lanzamiento (*release*) de forma que al iniciar uno nuevo puedas descargar todos los anteriores por si tienen alguna dependencia.
3. **Develop**: Es la rama que contiene las características (*features*) en desarrollo en una iteración, esta rama será posteriormente parte de Release mediante un *pull request*.
4. **Feature**: Es la rama que contiene el *feature* en el que estás trabajando personalmente (varios desarrolladores pueden trabajar en un feature), éste debe ser enviado a develop mediante un *full request*, por lo general aprobado por el líder técnico.
5. **Hotfix**: Es la rama que contiene cambios urgentes sobre master que permiten corregir un bug o resolver un error, éste debe ser enviado a master y se debe notificar a todos los desarrolladores para que puedan actualizar sus ramas.

**Herramientas**

Para esto existen herramientas que permiten simplificar este proceso mediante comandos, por ejemplo git-flow http://danielkummer.github.io/git-flow-cheatsheet/

El cual te provee de los siguientes comandos, los cuales encapsulan los pasos intermedios para seguir el flujo:

```
git flow init
git flow feature start MYFEATURE
git flow feature finish MYFEATURE
git flow feature publish MYFEATURE
git flow release start RELEASE [BASE]
git flow release publish RELEASE
git flow hotfix start VERSION [BASENAME]
...
```

**Para usuarios avanzados**

Adicionalmente a este flujo, Git provee muchas herramientas que permiten mejorar nuestro flujo de trabajo, gestión de código y automatización.

Entre ellas puedo destacar :

- **Git Tree, Git Submodules**: Esto permite integrar repositorios de código independientes como parte de uno mayor para evitar repetir archivos, por ejemplo cuando tienes un repositorio para una librería y otro para una aplicación que usa la librería.
- **CI, Travis, Code Climate**: Herramientas de terceros que permiten automatizar revisión de código y ejecución de test lo que facilita la tarea de colaboración al tener siempre definido el status de consistencia del código después de hacer un merge sobre el *full request* enviado.
- **Markdown, Pull Request comments**, Etiquetas: Son utilidades que en particular pertenecen a Github, Bitbucket o Gitlab el cual permite crear un hilo de conversación sobre los *pull request*, etiquetar o enlazar un branch, *pull request*, *commit*, usuario o comentario y o crear texto enriquecido enriqueciendo el flujo.

Comment: No me queda claro cómo esto responde a la pregunta del OP.

Comment: Responde el cierre de la pregunta, que engloba la interrogante principal "A ver si me orientáis un poco sobre la forma correcta de trabajar con git.", la respuesta expone de forma mas amplia el correcto flujo de trabajo con git que sugiero que adopte lo cual mejora su forma de trabajo por encima de solo resolver un problema principal donde daría igual trabajar con git o svn

Answer (score 11):

Para trabajar desde dos ubicaciones diferentes, debes clonar el repositorio de github en ambos ordenadores y mantener actualizado ambos repositorios locales.

Cuando hagas modificaciones en el trabajo por ejemplo, añade los cambios al repositorio (`git add` y `git commit` correspondiente). Una vez hecho, sube los cambios al repositorio remoto que está en github:

`git push origin RAMA`

Si no trabajas con ninguna rama a parte de la rama `master`, sube los cambios a esta.

Cuando llegues a casa, solo necesitas traer los cambios que están en el repositorio remoto (github):

`git pull origin RAMA`

El nombre de la rama debe ser la misma, ya que estás especificando de de que rama te quieres traer los cambios a tu repositorio local.

Antes de añadir cualquier modificación nueva, siempre es recomendable verificar que no hay ningún cambio más actualizado en el repositorio remoto. Para esto, puedes utilizar el comando anterior `git pull`.

Saludos.

Answer (score 4):

Creo que la siguiente imágen representa el esquema de lo que quieres realizar.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Primero tienes que tener en cuenta, que tipo de repositorio es el que quieres crear o necesitas (bare vs non-bare). Encontré el siguiente artículo que explica en base a la imagen anterior [ver link](http://www.danielnavarroymas.com/repositorio-git-bare-vs-non-bare/)

Por otra parte, posiblemente no va con tu respuesta pero, creo te puede ser útil. Es un pequeño script que encontré para subir nuestros proyectos a git, el cual fué desarrollado por [**Alfonso Saavedra**](https://gist.github.com/son-link/890903)

```
#!/bin/bash

# UpToGit 0.1
# Actualiza facilmente tu repositorio Git
# (CC) 2011 Alfonso Saavedra "Son Link"
# http://sonlinkblog.blogspot.com
# Bajo licencia GNU/GPL

# Modo de uso: copia o mueve este script a /usr/bin o /usr/local/bin y desde el directorio donde se encuentre la copia de un repo git, ejecútalo de esta manera:
# uptogit <ficheros>

# Comprobamos si el directorio en el que estamos es de un repositorio git
if [ ! -d '.git' ]; then
    echo 'Esta carpeta no contiene un repositorio Git'
    exit -1
fi

# Ahora comprobamos si se le paso algun parametro
if [ $# == 0 ]; then
    echo "UpToGit: ¡Error! No se le a pasado ningún parámetro"
    echo "uptogit fichero1 fichero2 ... ficheroN"
    exit -1
else
    # Recorremos los parametros para comprobar si son ficheros o directorios
    for file in $*; do
        if [ ! -e $file ]; then
            echo "UpToGit: El archivo o directorio $file no existe"
            exit -1
        fi
    done

    # Si llegamos hasta aquí, indicamos a Git los archivos a subir
    git add $*

    # Esto nos pedira el mensaje del commit
    echo "Introduce el mensaje del commit:"
    read TXT
    git commit -m "$TXT"

    # Y terminamos subiendo los archivos
    git push origin master
fi
```

Por mi parte lo uso con [GitLab](https://gitlab.com/) y me corre muy bien. Bueno espero te sea útil.

Comment: Creo que ese diagrama corresponde al llamado SVN mode, el cual usa git como si se tratase de svn, cvs y otras soluciones algo anticuadas sin explotar el potencial de git, se recomienda para personas que están migrando o iniciando con git, pero se recomienda crecer en complejidad para mejorar el flujo de trabajo.

Answer (score 2):

Bueno, por una experiencia los consejo que yo seguí fueron:

1. **Branches o Ramas.**

Debes trabajar mucho con branches porque así puedes trabajar en un requerimiento sin afectar el master, ya que, si tienes algo a medio hacer le haces un push y continuas en casa sin afectar el entorno.

2. **Uso de las Pull request**

Me parece una manera organizada de que esas branches o ramas que creastes, vayan fusionandose con tu master. Adicionalmente si lo haces de esta forma y hay un error, es mas fácil hacerle rollback y mejor aún se disminuye el que se caiga en conflictos de código.

Recuerda que la idea es que ninguno de tus requerimiento en progreso dañen el master.

Comment: En este esquema personalmente recomiendo agregar un nivel bajo master, "develop" por ejemplo de forma que en master siempre tengas código productivo, asi puedes automatizar los pases a producción desde el repositorio, con aprobar un pull request en master

Answer (score -1):

Para trabajar en dos ordenadores diferentes al mismo tiempo usando Git, la solución que he dado a este problema para mi, es crear mi repositorio en una unidad externa: disco duro o Usb, esto permite mover tu desarrollo entre ordenadores y subir los cambios a tu github cuando sean reales y no cosas parciales, como si te tocaría con las opciones anteriores.

Desconozco cual lenguaje de programación usas, pero en Php configuras el http.conf y define el DocumentRoot en la unidad externa. Si es java, debería configurar tu  IDE para que busque el proyecto en la unidad externa.